# SOAPFaultException:Failed to send request while using the SOAP webservice

Tags: soap

```
java.rmi.RemoteException: SOAP Fault:javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException: Failed to send request
Detail:
<detail><bea_fault:stacktrace xmlns:bea_fault="http://www.bea.com/servers/wls70/webservice/fault/1.0.0">java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:559)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.&lt;init&gt;(HttpsClient.java:272)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1014)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
        at weblogic.webservice.binding.http11.Http11ClientBinding.send(Http11ClientBinding.java:438)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.handler.ClientHandler.handleRequest(ClientHandler.java:38)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.HandlerChainImpl.handleRequest(HandlerChainImpl.java:144)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.ClientDispatcher.send(ClientDispatcher.java:235)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.ClientDispatcher.dispatch(ClientDispatcher.java:146)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.DefaultOperation.invoke(DefaultOperation.java:449)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.DefaultOperation.invoke(DefaultOperation.java:435)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.rpc.StubImpl._invoke(StubImpl.java:306)
        at com.cengage.ips.IPSInquiryWebServiceSoap_Stub.itemInquiry(IPSInquiryWebServiceSoap_Stub.java:64)
        at main.java.com.cengage.ips.ServiceManager.getItemResponse(ServiceManager.java:57)
        at main.java.com.cengage.ips.process.ResponseHandler.itemResponseHandler(ResponseHandler.java:49)
        at main.java.com.cengage.ips.IPSIntegration.process(IPSIntegration.java:63)
        at main.java.com.cengage.ips.IPSIntegration.run(IPSIntegration.java:37)
        at main.java.com.cengage.ips.IPSIntegration.main(IPSIntegration.java:28)
</bea_fault:stacktrace></detail>; nested exception is:
        javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException: Failed to send request
        at com.cengage.ips.IPSInquiryWebServiceSoap_Stub.itemInquiry(IPSInquiryWebServiceSoap_Stub.java:69)
        at main.java.com.cengage.ips.ServiceManager.getItemResponse(ServiceManager.java:57)
        at main.java.com.cengage.ips.process.ResponseHandler.itemResponseHandler(ResponseHandler.java:49)
        at main.java.com.cengage.ips.IPSIntegration.process(IPSIntegration.java:63)
        at main.java.com.cengage.ips.IPSIntegration.run(IPSIntegration.java:37)
        at main.java.com.cengage.ips.IPSIntegration.main(IPSIntegration.java:28)
Caused by: javax.xml.rpc.soap.SOAPFaultException: Failed to send request
        at weblogic.webservice.core.ClientDispatcher.receive(ClientDispatcher.java:317)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.ClientDispatcher.dispatch(ClientDispatcher.java:147)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.DefaultOperation.invoke(DefaultOperation.java:449)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.DefaultOperation.invoke(DefaultOperation.java:435)
        at weblogic.webservice.core.rpc.StubImpl._invoke(StubImpl.java:306)
        at com.cengage.ips.IPSInquiryWebServiceSoap_Stub.itemInquiry(IPSInquiryWebServiceSoap_Stub.java:64)
        ... 5 more
```

Am trying to use one SOAP web service. I have tried executing this application in my local windows machine using some cmd script file. Its working fine. But when i try in Unix server with shell script am getting the above error. Can someone please suggest the solution?

Comment: If your Java SOAP call succeeds in Windows but fails on Unix, it would seem to imply that the problem may lie with the environment of the latter.  Can you even ping the server from Unix?

Comment: Pind command is not working in that unix server. I tried telnet <servername>.... It is showing trying <ip address> for long time...

Comment: Check to see if you are behind a firewall, if there is something else blocking you.

Comment: in my local windows machine, if i change the soap service url from http to https, then its not working. I tried both http and https in unix server. Its not working